# get value inside DOM setAttribute JavaScript using BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, regex, dom, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the value inside the `setAttribute` element in JavaScript using **BeautifulSoup**. I tried using **regular expression** but it returns `None`.

The `script` tag is as follows

```
<script>            
     var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
     iframe.setAttribute("src", "Value i need to get");
     iframe.frameBorder=0;
     iframe.scrolling="no";
     iframe.width="300px";
     iframe.height="24px";
     document.getElementById("m_iframe").appendChild(iframe);               
</script>
```

Python code:

```
        html=url.read()
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        p = re.compile('\s+iframe.setAttribute("src",\s+"(.*)");')
        all_script  = soup.find_all("script", {"src":False})
        for individual_script in all_script:
            all_value =  individual_script.string
            if all_value:            
                m = p.match(all_value)
                print m
```

what's wrong in my code?

How to get that value?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your regex, the issue is that you haven't escaped the parentheses of the setAttribute function, so it's just treating them like a capture group. Try this regex instead: `\s+iframe.setAttribute("src",\s+"(.*)");'

You shouldn't really need BeautifulSoup at all here if you're doing a regex scrape... something like this should suffice:

```
html = url.read()
r = re.compile(r'\s+iframe\.setAttribute\("src",\s+"(.*)"\);')
match = r.match(html)
if match:
    print match.group()
```

Comment: still getting `None` as output

Comment: Can you post the code you're using? You shouldn't really need BeautifulSoup at all if you're just doing it the regex way. Something like

    `html = url.read()`
    `matches = re.match(r'<your regex here>', html)`
    `print matches.groups()`

Comment: Sorry, I thought you might have a snippet that was pure regex without BeautifulSoup. I've updated my answer with a snippet that shouldn't require BS.

Comment: getting an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that re.match wants to match the entire string. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Nothing is getting printed

Comment: Are you sure your html variable actually contains this string? I've run my regex against your example html and it's working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99792/discussion-between-user305774-and-jeremy-rans).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple split to extract the text you want, I use this often as I am not that good with regex.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html>
    <script>
     var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
     iframe.setAttribute("src", "Value i need to get");
     iframe.frameBorder=0;
     iframe.scrolling="no";
     iframe.width="300px";
     iframe.height="24px";
     document.getElementById("m_iframe").appendChild(iframe);
    </script>
</html>
    """
start = 'iframe.setAttribute("src", "'
end = '");'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
cols = soup.findAll('script')
for i in cols:
    text_you_need = ((i.text.split(start))[1].split(end)[0])
    print(text_you_need)
```

and you get what you want:

```
Value i need to get
```

You can use the same snippet to get text between two strings, which covers most of what I intend to do for scraping.

Comment: when i use this with beautiful soap i get this error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: my code looks like this `soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
            cols=soup.findAll('script')
            for i in cols:
                text_you_need = ((i.split(start))[1].split(end)[0])`

Comment: your variable i should be a string here, so try ```for i in cols: text_you_need = ((i.text.split(start))[1].split(end)[0])```

Comment: @user305774  updated my answer, which explains my previous comment.. I have checked this script and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
\s+iframe\.setAttribute\("src",\s+"([^"]+)"\);
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/oO0fZ3/2